# nvidia 820m problem

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, windows

How to disable graphic card permanently on Ubuntu 14.04.

- graphic card is a 820m
- laptop is hp 15 r203tx
- bios version is up to date

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: how to disable nvidia graphic permanently in ubuntu

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that very relevant information there instead of "what to do, please suggest"...  **;-)***

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of disabling the nVidia card in Ubuntu (and is also the way I'm running until I need it) is to go to your BIOS and disable it there. (It will say something like `On-board graphics` or `Intel integrated`)

That way, all the drivers are still installed and whenever you need the power of the nVidia, you just reboot, go into the BIOS and enable it again.

That way, you get great battery life when you need it and get the power when you need it as well.  *You* decide.

### ;-)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: i am using hp laptop and in bios there is no such option

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact model number and BIOS version so I can look that up for you...

Comment: bios version is F.39

Comment: There is no section in the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04409502) of the BIOS settings, so you'll have to look for it yourself as I don't have the same hardware as you...  **:-(**

Answer (score 0):

To disable cards in software install **[Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)**. This will install `bbswitch` for you.

See the usage section [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch)to disable the card. Do not build from here unless you know what you're doing.

If the first link doesn't install `bbswitch`, try [this](http://ubuntuguide.net/turn-off-discrete-nvidia-optimus-graphics-card-ubuntu).

Comment: please elaborte step by step or give me link

Comment: in google there are lot of confusion

Comment: @ghostfreak029 both are wiki articles...they have instructions.